# checkboxes in php - problem with access

Tags: php, arrays

i need to reproduce with the code below something like:

```
myformdata[languages1]
myformdata[languages2]
myformdata[languages3]
```

But with this code only reproduce `myformdata[languages`

```
    <?php
    $sql=mysql_query("select id_spoken_languages, language, path from spoken_languages");
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id=$row['id_spoken_languages'];
    $data=$row['language'];
    $flag=$row['path'];
    echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages'.$i++.']' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n");
    } 
    ?>
```

i already tried remove the increment and only access with `$form_data_array["languages"][1]` but in this case i get:

**Notice**:  Uninitialized string offset: 1 in **C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\validation2.php** on line **9**

but if i use `$form_data_array["languages"][0], no error is showed, seems like all checkbox have the 
index 0.

what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Get a proper editor, and change the quotes around `$i++` from `'` to  `"`. Any decent editor could've shown you that.

Comment: You could get rid of the full stops and single quotes completely as  php will display `$i++` as a value when placed within speech marks (double quotes)...

Comment: No, you can't, the `++` operator does not work inside quotes, it will just be regarded as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your output string may be incorrect. Try this one:

```
echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages".$i++."]' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n");
```

I replaced the two instance of single quotes before and after the increment output with double quotes.

Also note, there is no need to increment in PHP. All you need to add is two empty brackets `[]` and PHP will take care of the incrementing itself. So if you'd like to access the input with `$_POST["languages"][1]` you can do so by generating the following: `name='languages[]'`.

Comment: thanks. This is exactly what i pretend: name='myformdata[languages][]'

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $sql=mysql_query("select id_spoken_languages, language, path from spoken_languages");
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id=$row['id_spoken_languages'];
    $data=$row['language'];
    $flag=$row['path'];
    echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages".$i++."]' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n");
    } 
    ?>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like quotes are messed up:

```
echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages" . $i++ . "]' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $i++;
echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages$i]' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages'.$i++.']' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n");
```

to

```
 echo nl2br ("<input type='checkbox' name='myformdata[languages" .$i++. "]' value='$id' class='semLargura'>$data <img style='float:right; margin-top:5px; border:1px solid grey;' src='$flag'></img> \n");
```

Also I'm not 100% sure whether `[]`'s are allowed for names of elements. If not you could consider change the name to be like

```
myformdata_1 ect...
```